# Change the image without recompilation

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to change the background image of the Windows form application without being recompiled. All I need to do is to change the file and the background images changes itself.

Is there any way I can achieve it ?

Assume i have a background image of a circle. now i need to change the image from circle to square just by simply changing the image file in the Image Folder .

Comment: How do you mean with being recompiled, you want to have a random image as background every start up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the form's load event, do:

```
me.BackgroundImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("ReletivePathToImageFile")
```

You can leave the image set to anything you want in the designer, this line of code will overwrite the image when the form loads at runtime.

Here is an updated version to use streams as suggested by Jens:

```
    Using s As New IO.FileStream("PathToFile", IO.FileMode.Open)
        Dim img As Image = Image.FromStream(s)
        s.Close()
        Me.BackgroundImage = img
    End Using
```

Comment: but the issue is if i set the image from the code i cannot see the effect in design view is there anyway around ?

Comment: @Bradley: I suggest to not use FromFile() like in your code sample as this would leave the FileHandle open during the full application's life time. Better use Streams instead.

Comment: @ShujaatSiddiqui If you want to preview it in the designer, just set the new image in the designer.  Like I said, the image you set in the designer will not "permanent", it will be overwritten at runtime by reading the contents of the image file specified.  No recompiling needed.

Comment: u mean to say than if i add any image in design view i must have to mention its path in code ? isn't overhead ?

Comment: No, I'm saying that if you want to be able to change the form's background without recompiling the application the code I posted will do that.  If you want to be able to see that change in the designer  BEFORE it's compiled, then you will have to actually point the designer to the new file.  I'm a little confused now though, if you are interested in changing the background at runtime, why do you need to see it in design view?

Comment: so that i could design my application according to the given scenario. i think this is the only possible option we have. because i myself could not find any other solution. i have to apply your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the post build events.  If you right click on the project in visual studio and click on properties, there is a tab called Build Events.  This works similar to command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Don't just hardcode your image, load it from file on each start. Thus you can change your image just by replacing the file. I don't see any problems here that should make you consider manipulating your project without recompiling it...